QGIS build on Windows 11
I am new to building QGIS.
I have been able to get the CMAKE to run completely after resolving all of the dependencies.  My question is related to where the target .exe/binary for QGIS is written to. Per the cmake, it looks like it's down in the default debug directory, but I am not seeing any executable or zip file.
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/OSGeo4W64/out/build/x64-Debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted toolchain configurations.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.
Can someone assist me with this, or let me know if there are any settings that I need to set?
For context, I am using VS2019 and downloaded the master branch of QGIS about 2 weeks ago.
For additional context, this is the only file that is appearing in the output/bin folder and most folders are touched and a few files are written, but nothing showing any sort of errors/issues with the process.

